# why is $\varnothing$ not counted when counting the number of elements in a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is the question I have searched on google several times by a different way, but I never got a helpful answer. So, here is the question. If $\varnothing$ is the empty set and it is also a subset of every set then why don't we count it when checking the cardinality of that set.
for example: set $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$
its cardinality is $n(A)=4$, but why not $n(A)=5$, as there is $\varnothing$  in it as well.

Comment: Cardinality counts **elements**, not subsets. $\emptyset$ is a **subset**, not an element, of every set.

Comment: When we talk about the empty set, we do not refer to it as "phi" even though the symbols look similar: $\phi$ is phi, and $\emptyset$ is the empty set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the subset relation and the membership relation. It is true that $$\forall A:\emptyset\subset A$$ but it is not true that $$\forall A:\emptyset\in A$$ Your set is a perfect counterexample. We don't count the empty set as a fifth element because it isn't IN the set.

Answer (score 1):

There is a distinction between being an element of the set and being a subset. The empty set is contained in every set as a subset.. this does not mean that it is an element of the set. As an example, the two sets $\{ \varnothing, a \}$ and $\{a \}$ are completely different, but both contain the empty set as a subset.